# How to import i18n in Vue file

Tags: javascript, internationalization, vue-i18n

I am using i18n library in Vue.js for language translation. I want to to import in it my script and store a value in data, but I have trouble with importing it. How should I import it? I tried with `import $t from "./i18n";` but that just returns this error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './i18n'`

here is my code:

```
script>
import Header from "../components/Header";
import $ from "jquery";
import $t from "./i18n";

export default {
  name: "GroupPermissions",
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showAddGroupDialog: false,
      updatePermissionDialog: false,
      itemsToBeDeleted: [],
      permissions: $t("groupPermissions.table.permissions")
    };
```

and my main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import VueMaterial from "vue-material";
import "vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css";
import "vue-material/dist/theme/default.css";
import "vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css";
import $ from "jquery";
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";
import i18n from "./i18n";
import "@/plugins/echarts";
import Sticky from 'vue-sticky-directive'

Vue.component("multiselect", Multiselect);
Vue.use(VueMaterial);
Vue.use(Sticky);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  $,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like use [vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n), in your main.js you should import `vue-i18n` library first and create an i18n variable like this:

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages: { 'en': { title: 'Title' }},
});
```

and pass the `i18n` var to your Vue in main.js as you did it:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  $,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

After this, in your component you will have a `this.$t('title')` method that will return with 'Title' value.

This link may help for you: http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/started.html#javascript

Answer (score 2):

Imre showed how to install the *vue-i18n* globally. I'll just add that you can also import an instance of `i18n` and use it in any javascript file, not only within Vue components.

If you export `i18n` like this

```js
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

export const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages: { 'en': { title: 'Title' }},
});
```

you can then use it in Vue components, though `using this.$t()` is preferable.

```
<script>
import Header from "../components/Header";
import $ from "jquery";
import { i18n } from "./i18n";

export default {
  name: "GroupPermissions",
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showAddGroupDialog: false,
      updatePermissionDialog: false,
      itemsToBeDeleted: [],
      permissions: i18n.t("groupPermissions.table.permissions")
    };
</script>
```

But more relevantly, you can use this anywhere else.

```
//some-function.js
import { i18n } from "./i18n";

function someFunction() {
  console.log(i18n.t(...));
}
```